# How can I enable Window Authentication on IIS (7+) by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I need to make a web application which can handle other web application (asp.net, IIS)
How can I enable Window Authentication on IIS (7+) by C#
Thank you

Comment: What have you got in your web.cofig file?

Comment: Go through this [**link1**](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication) and [**Link2**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx) might help you..

Comment: Thank all, link 1 is help me

Comment: ah, i forgot mention, your app Pool need have right to do. Because my site is running on local network and i change to LocalSystem for full right

Answer (score 0):

In web.config set `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

Thanks